# 2 Pin Flame Sensor

Tags: arduino, sensor

I recently found a 2 Pin flame sensor. It looks just like an LED except it's black. It is not a module and I couldn't find any wiring tutorials for these, just for modules. Does anyone know how to wire this? Also, why would it be wired so? Thank you
[image: flame sensor]

Comment: If this is Arduino specific, maybe it belongs over on Arduino SE. Also, you probably need to supply more details, like a datasheet or something.

Comment: You've got to at least provide a picture or something. "2 Pin flame sensor" isn't much to go on.

Comment: Sorry for not adding a photo. It is there now. Thank you

Comment: My best guess is that this is an IR photo-transistor or IR photo-diode.  It **IS** possible that it also includes signal conditioning but, based on the shape, I think that is highly unlikely.

Comment: I received one of these among many other parts in an Arduino Uno learning kit,. I knew it was a flame sensor but it was very hard to find information about it, until I knew it's probably a YG100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the IR photo-transistor used in the common Arduino flame detector modules. Explained [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Modules-Flame-Sensor/) and [here](http://www.sunfounder.com/index.php?c=downloadscs&a=Manualdetails&id=100&name=).

Here is how it works. The photo-transistor starts conducting when it gets IR light from a flame or any source strong enough. A comparator can be used to convert it to a digital output. The second link above has a schematic that the Arduino modules use.

That being said, this could also be a photo diode since I couldn't find any official specification on this component. The working principle would be similar but the wiring would be different. Basically you could wire this like any other photo diode or transistor. I would wire it in different ways and measure the changes in current/voltage when pointing to a flame. You could start with the schematic below and use a multi-meter to measure the output voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiBvw9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a [YG1006 flame sensor](http://www.gotronic.fr/pj-835.pdf).

I found this in another kit's description: "The Flame sensor is a high-speed and highly sensitive NPN silicon photo transistor based on the YG1006. It can be used to detect fire or other wavelength at 760nm ~ 1100nm light. Response time is 15us, supply voltage is 3.3-5V; output is analog."

Comment: "Due to  its  black  epoxy  the  device  is sensitive to infrared radiation". Loses something in the translation.